# Qt QTableWidget's gray dotted border around a selected cell

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm wondering if anyone knows of, perhaps a flag to disable the gray dotted border that appears when you single click on a QTableWidget's cell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

C++: `tableWidget->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);`

Python: `tableWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)`

Be aware that you will lose the ability to process keyboard events, but mouse events will work fine.

Answer (score 16):

It seems like you want to remove the border when the cell gets the focus.

Try editing the Stylesheet as follows.

```
QTableWidget {
    outline: 0;
}
```

This worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

That gray dotted border indicates that that widget has focus.

Setting the below at the widget level should do the trick.

```
setFocusPolicy( Qt::NoFocus )
```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to do it for me without affecting widget's focus policy and using qss is to create the following custom delegate and install it for table:

***.h:**

```
class FocusControlDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate {
    public:
        FocusControlDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);
        virtual void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const;        
        void setFocusBorderEnabled(bool enabled);

    protected:
        bool f_focus_border_enabled;
    };
```

***.cpp:**

```
FocusControlDelegate::FocusControlDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent) {
    f_focus_border_enabled = false;
}

void FocusControlDelegate::setFocusBorderEnabled(bool enabled) {
    f_focus_border_enabled = enabled;
}

void FocusControlDelegate::initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem *option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option, index);
    if(!f_focus_border_enabled && option->state & QStyle::State_HasFocus)
        option->state = option->state & ~QStyle::State_HasFocus;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`qApp->setStyleSheet ( " QTableWidget::item:focus { border: 0px }" );`

Comment: almost. but if we use alternate background color, it changes the selection background color to alternate background color. Add this fix `QTableWidget::item:focus { border: 0px; background-color: #<your selection background color> }`

Answer (score 0):

QPushButton {
    outline: none;
}